# Want to add files to OVA package

Tags: installation

I have an OVA package with two images and an OVF descriptor file.
During deploymeny time is it possible to add some files(.tgz, .iso. qcow2....)?
If so, how can we achieve this and also where these files will be available after stack launching .

Answer (score 0):

An OVA package is just a `tar`'red OVF package, distributed as a single package. [The OVF standard](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0243_1.1.0.pdf) provides room for extra files: it specifies that a valid OVF package must include an OVF descriptor with extension .ovf, an OVF manifest with extension .mf,  possibly an OVF certificate with extension .cert,  a disk image file (of format vmdk, for instance) and then it leaves room for additional files.

If there is no certificate, then you can omit the manifest. But if the manifest is present, it **must** include the SHA-1 hash of the extra files (in addition to the other files) in the form:

```
SHA1(my_second_disk.vmdk)= SHA1_Hash_of_file_my_second_disk.vmdk
```

So, strictly speaking there are no limitations to the kind of files that you may add to the package. However, lest this amounts to nothing more than a piggy-back ride, you will have to include in the descriptor (the `.ovf`) file instructions to the hypervisor on what to do with these extra files. The descriptor file is an XML file, whose format is painstakingly detailed by the above document, painstakingly because it is the essence of the package. Not knowing exactly what you want to do with your extra files, I will simply post the Table of Contents of the document above, which gives you an idea of the various sections contained inside the descriptor file.

[image]

Comment: Hi Marius.....My requirement is I have an OVA package with an option to choose number of VMs required before launching the stack in ATLAS(For all Vm bootable image is same .iso). In ATLAS there is a provision for user to inject some files into any of the VM before launching. However the files are limited to ".xml" and ".txt" format. But I want to inject a ".tgz". Is this possible?

Comment: @user528639 This is a totally different question than the one you posted. By asking it like this, you are obtaining only my help (and I do **not** know the answer). You should accept my answer to this question, then ask a new one, possibly with a reference to this one.

Comment: Yes...I accept your answer for the question posted is correct.
My question is not completely projecting my requirement that is my I put a comment with my requirement more clearly.
and yes...I need a help on this :)